# ReactJS Redux State (global state) + React.Context (local state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context

I am new in ReactJS World, and I need your opinion related to ReactJS state.

I started to use Redux in my application for global state (global modules), it fits really good because any time I need the state, I can call it from anywhere.
In Redux I like to keep notifications, they are shown on all pages in my App, also I keep app version (demo/live), in other words I try to keep in Redux (global state) global values.

In my App I also have pages, each page have its specific state and components. When the client leaves the page, I do not need its state anymore. That's why I do not like to keep the state in Redux, because when it leaves the page, the page state is still keeped in Redux.
So, in this case seems to be correct to keep page state in React.Context (+ React.Reducer).

React.Context Pros:

- when the client leaves the page, the state is removed automatically
- when the client access the page, the state is clean, because the state is created togheter with the component

React.Context Cons:

- it's complicated to combine Redux state and Context state
- two types of store, means more code to maintain (React.Context has less functionality)

How do you think, it is ok to use Redux togheter with React.Context as I explained, it solve the problem or it creates a lot more problems?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: When you say about local state, not sure why you are not using only hooks. Do you need context?

Comment: @O.o Because a page may have multiple components, so I need context to pass state to page children components.

Answer (score -1):

Attempting to manage two state management containers can become unwieldy and is also not ideal for the sake of consistency.  I personally like React Hooks + Context, as I find it simple and clean.  You should be able to obtain the same result with either on their own, but if you have a notification system already setup with Redux that is another thing to keep in consideration.  Also, you can still utilize Redux and have the Redux store cleared when a user leaves a page with the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method. Read up on both of them, there's a lot of useful documentation out there, as well as informative comparison articles- see which you like the most and think would work best for your specific situation.

**Documentation**

- React-Hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html
- React-Context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
- React-Redux: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/why-use-react-redux

**Articles**

- https://academind.com/tutorials/reactjs-redux-vs-context-api/
- (Opinionated towards Context + Hooks): https://blog.logrocket.com/use-hooks-and-context-not-react-and-redux/
- (Opinionated towards Redux): https://blog.softwaremill.com/react-context-api-vs-redux-the-eternal-dichotomy-24639907fc98